# How do C functions like qsort work with different datatypes?

Tags: c, generics, void-pointers

In `stdlib.h`, there is a declaration of the function qsort() with prototype:

```
void qsort( void *ptr, size_t count, size_t size,
        int (*comp)(const void *, const void *) );
```

Obviously it is a generic programming.
I wonder how it implement, how to get the element from the void * type?

Comment: Note to most answers: This question is **not** about how to use qsort(), it's about how e.g. qsort internally can figure out the location of the elements in a void*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void *` pointers are casted according to the `size_t size` (the 3rd argument in `qsort`)

First we typecast the `void*` to `char*` and then do pointer arithmetic according to the `size` (because char takes `1` byte so adding the size will give correct pointer arithmetic )

EDIT : (for in built data types)

```
char *ptr = (char*)vp; //here vp is void *p

*(ptr + (n-1)*size); //will give you nth element
```

e.g.

```
size =1 and want 3rd element it means it will give you 3rd char
size =4 and want 3rd element it means it will give you 3rd int or float
size =2 and want 3rd element it means it will give you 3rd short int
size =8 and want 3rd element it means it will give you 3rd double
```

NOTE : size is implementation defined so it may vary to compilers

Comment: Yes, and what I want to know is the specific process. For example, how to get the 3th element in ptr?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void compare_first_to_rest(void *ptr, size_t nelem, 
   size_t size, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*)) {
    unsigned i;
    for(i = 1; i < nelem; ++i)
        {
        int res = cmp(ptr, (char*)ptr + i * size);
        if(res < 0)
            printf("First element is less than element at %u\n", i);
        else if(res > 0)
            printf("First element is greater than element at %u\n", i);
        else
            printf("First element is equal to element at %u\n", i);
        }
}

int icmp(const void *x, const void *y) {
   return *(int*)x - *(int*)y;
}

int main()
{
   int x[] = { 5, 3, 6, 2, 4, 8, -1, 10 };
   compare_first_to_rest(x, 8, sizeof(int), icmp);
}
```

As you can see, `compare_first_to_rest' doesn't know about the type of the elements it receives in its first argument. But knowing the size of each one, it can get a pointer to every one of them, and let the function pointer do the job.

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter is a function pointer. As you implicitly mentioned You must have implemented this function somewhere.
But as you implement it, you do know what king of pointer is actually your void* element.

In your comp function, you have to cast your 2 parameters into the pointer type you want to work with, as below:

```
int myCompFn(const void * e1, const void * e2)
{
    MyType *elem1=(MyType*)e1;
    MyType *elem2=(MyType*)e2;
    ... /* then compare elem1 and elem2 regarding to there definition */
}
```